# How to set default compiler to be Clang?

Tags: python, c++, macos, gcc, clang

I have a Mac osx yosemite 10.10.3, and installed gcc 5.1.0 on my own recently.  This decision has caused me a lot of problems.  Although I then brew uninstalled gcc, nevertheless when I write gcc --version, I still get

```
gcc (GCC) 5.1.0.
```

The fact that it is/appears to be the default compiler instead of clang has created a number of problems when compiling. Sometimes I can avoid these by in certain situations writing -toolset=clang on the command line but other times such as when I'm installing a python module via, e.g.,  python setup.py install, it is seems unavoidable.

I have tried to add the following to my bashrc profile

```
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang++
```

but to no avail.

Obviously I don't want to reinstall my operating system.  Any tips?

To clarify, the history of this question is this: when I recently tried to compile something using boost, .bjam was confusing c++11 and c++98 libraries. Adding

```
-toolset=clang
```

appeared to fix the issue. However when I am now installing a particular python module via

```
python setup.py install
```

importing it gives me the following in python;

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: dlopen(somescript.so, 2):          Symbol not found: __ZTINSt8ios_base7failureB5cxx11E Referenced from: somescript.so Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

Comment: The title is misleading; GCC and Clang are both competitor C compiler suites. If you have a call to CC, then it should go to whatever C compiler you have defined to be the value of CC. If you call GCC, then it'll go to GCC.

Comment: That's true, when I write, cc --version
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)..  I think I have trouble articulating the problem then.  The point is that the wrong libraries are being used when I compile...

Comment: Where is the `gcc` located? To find out, use `which gcc`.

Comment: @Jens Höpken To clarify, the history of this question is this:  when I recently tried to compile something using boost, .bjam was confusing c++11 and c++98 libraries.  Adding
`-toolset=clang`
appeared to fix the issue.  However when I am now installing a particular python module via
`python setup.py install,`
importing it gives me the following in python; 

    `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: dlopen(somescript.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZTINSt8ios_base7failureB5cxx11E
    Referenced from: somescript.so
    Expected in: dynamic lookup`

Comment: ^ Then you should have asked about this instead!

Comment: @user45254: When I compare `gcc-5`, which comes with homebrew, it is located in `/usr/local/bin/gcc-5`, whereas `gcc` is located in `/usr/bin/gcc` and is the official XCode `gcc`. At least this is how it looks on my machine. I know this doesn't help you, but just to clarify the paths...

Comment: @Jens Höpken
which gcc-5 doesn't exist but that's because I brew uninstalled gcc just now to see if that changed anything (it didn't)

Comment: @ShotgunNinja thanks, I added to original question

Comment: I asked the question more directly here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031921/python-not-importing-module-perhaps-gcc-being-used-to-compile-the-python-libra